# Omnidirectional shadow mapping with depth cubemap

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, shadow

I'm working with omnidirectional point lights. I already implemented shadow mapping using a cubemap texture as color attachement of 6 framebuffers, and encoding the light-to-fragment distance in each pixel of it.

Now I would like, if this is possible, to change my implementation this way:

- 1) attach a depth cubemap texture to the depth buffer of my framebuffers, instead of colors.
- 2) render depth only, do not write color in this pass
- 3) in the main pass, read the depth from the cubemap texture, convert it to a distance, and check whether the current fragment is occluded by the light or not.

My problem comes when converting back a depth value from the cubemap into a distance. I use the light-to-fragment vector (in world space) to fetch my depth value in the cubemap. At this point, I don't know which of the six faces is being used, nor what 2D texture coordinates match the depth value I'm reading. Then how can I convert that depth value to a distance?

Here are snippets of my code to illustrate:

Depth texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &TextureHandle);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, TextureHandle);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
              Width, Height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Framebuffers construction:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO->FrameBufferID);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO->FrameBufferID);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
            GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, TextureHandle, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
}
```

The piece of fragment shader I'm trying to write to achieve my code:

```
float ComputeShadowFactor(samplerCubeShadow ShadowCubeMap, vec3 VertToLightWS)
{   
    float ShadowVec = texture(ShadowCubeMap, vec4(VertToLightWS, 1.0));
    ShadowVec = DepthValueToDistance(ShadowVec);
    if (ShadowVec * ShadowVec > dot(VertToLightWS, VertToLightWS))
        return 1.0;

    return 0.0;
}
```

The DepthValueToDistance function being my actual problem.

Comment: "Is there a solution to my problem?" Convert distance to depth, compare with stored depth in cubemap. "unappliable for cube map shadows" I think 5..7 years ago somebody called "ron frazier" wrote an article about using cubemaps for shadow mapping.

Comment: @SigTerm http://www.ronfrazier.net/apparition/index.html?appmain=research/index.html is what I think you are talking about.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: Yep. I **think** it was [this](http://www.ronfrazier.net/apparition/index.html?appmain=research/index.html) article. It is obviously possible to do something similar with modern OpenGL/better precision (there are floating point textures, GLSL, `*shadow` samplers, etc) - I just don't have a working snippet nearby and don't feel like writing one.

Comment: Although this page is quite old, it gives the reason why I should do distance-to-depth conversion instead of the inverse: "unfortunately the depth buffer uses a camera space z distance for the depth value rather than the Cartesian distance". Finding the matching "camera z distance" from a world space vector into one of the cubemap face is easy. I managed to have my shadow working now. When I'll have cleaned a bit my code, I will clean the question and post the answer. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the solution was to convert the light-to-fragment vector to a depth value, instead of converting the depth read from the cubemap into a distance.

Here is the modified shader code:

```
float VectorToDepthValue(vec3 Vec)
{
    vec3 AbsVec = abs(Vec);
    float LocalZcomp = max(AbsVec.x, max(AbsVec.y, AbsVec.z));

    const float f = 2048.0;
    const float n = 1.0;
    float NormZComp = (f+n) / (f-n) - (2*f*n)/(f-n)/LocalZcomp;
    return (NormZComp + 1.0) * 0.5;
}

float ComputeShadowFactor(samplerCubeShadow ShadowCubeMap, vec3 VertToLightWS)
{   
    float ShadowVec = texture(ShadowCubeMap, vec4(VertToLightWS, 1.0));
    if (ShadowVec + 0.0001 > VectorToDepthValue(VertToLightWS))
        return 1.0;

    return 0.0;
}
```

Explaination on `VectorToDepthValue(vec3 Vec)` :

`LocalZComp` corresponds to what would be the Z-component of the given `Vec` into the matching frustum of the cubemap. It's actually the largest component of `Vec` (for instance if Vec.y is the biggest component, we will look either on the Y+ or the Y- face of the cubemap).

If you look at this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering#Mathematics), you will understand the math just after (I kept it in a formal form for understanding), which simply convert the `LocalZComp` into a normalized Z value (between in [-1..1]) and then map it into [0..1] which is the actual range for depth buffer values. (assuming you didn't change it). `n` and `f` are the near and far values of the frustums used to generate the cubemap.

`ComputeShadowFactor` then just compare the depth value from the cubemap with the depth value computed from the fragment-to-light vector (named `VertToLightWS` here), also add a small depth bias (which was missing in the question), and returns 1 if the fragment is not occluded by the light.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add more details regarding the derivation.

Let **V** be the light-to-fragment direction vector.

As Benlitz already said, the **Z** value in the respective cube side frustum/"eye space" can be calculated by taking the max of the absolute values of **V**'s components.

```
Z = max(abs(V.x),abs(V.y),abs(V.z))
```

Then, to be precise, we should negate **Z** because in OpenGL, the negative Z-axis points into the screen/view frustum.

Now we want to get the depth buffer "compatible" value of that **-Z**.

Looking at the OpenGL perspective matrix...

> http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_projectionmatrix_eq16.png
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN7ke.png (backup link)

...we see that, for any homogeneous vector multiplied with that matrix, the resulting z value is completely independent of the vector's x and y components.

So we can simply multiply this matrix with the homogeneous vector (0,0,**-Z**,1) and we get the vector (components):

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = (-Z * -(f+n) / (f-n)) + (-2*f*n / (f-n))
w = Z
```

Then we need to do the perspective divide, so we divide z by w (**Z**) which gives us:

```
z' = (f+n) / (f-n) - 2*f*n / (Z* (f-n))
```

This z' is in OpenGL's normalized device coordinate (NDC) range [-1,1] and needs to be transformed into a depth buffer compatible range of [0,1]:

```
z_depth_buffer_compatible = (z' + 1.0) * 0.5
```

Further notes:

- It might make sense to upload the results of (f+n), (f-n) and (f*n) as shader uniforms to save computation.
- **V** needs to be in world space since the shadow cube map is normally axis aligned in world space thus the "*max(abs(V.x),abs(V.y),abs(V.z))*"-part only works if **V** is a world space direction vector.