# Omnidirectional Lighting in OpenGL/GLSL 4.1

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've gotten shadows working properly for my Directional Lights, but I'm a little stumped when it comes to Point Lights. My idea is to use a cube map to render the depth from all six sides surrounding the light. So far, that's all working and good. I have verified this step by rendering each face of my cube to a 2D image, and it appears to be correct.

Now I'm trying to get the shadows to show up in the world. To do so, I am using GLSL's samplerCubeShadow data type. With it, I do:

```
vec3 lightToFrag = light.position - fragPos
float lenLightToFrag = length(lightToFrag)
vec3 normLightToFrag = normalize(lightToFrag)
float shadow = texture(depthTexture, vec4(normLightToFrag, lightToFrag))
```

I've tried a number of configurations, and this always renders my scene in black. Any ideas? My fragPos is just the model matrix times the vertex position. Should I be applying the light's model-view matrix to it? Or, similarly, should I be applying the world's model-view matrix to the light? Any feedback is really appreciated!

Comment: Here your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786951/omnidirectional-shadow-mapping-with-depth-cubemap/10789527#10789527 if you store depth values in cubemap you need to convert lightToFrag to depth value to compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are storing depth values in cubemap;

AFAIK cubemap is an AABB in world space, so **you need to do calculations in world space**. In your case `light.position` and `fragPos` must be in world space, or provide alternative variables/members if you use these names in view space in somewhere else e.g. per-fragment light calculations

Also you need to convert lightToFrag to depth value before pass to `texture`.
This answer shows how to convert lightToFrag to depth value: [Omnidirectional shadow mapping with depth cubemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786951/omnidirectional-shadow-mapping-with-depth-cubemap/10789527#10789527)

Here my implementation (I removed #ifdef SHAD_CUBE because others use same name):

```
uniform samplerCubeShadow uShadMap;
uniform vec2              uFarNear;

float depthValue(const in vec3 v) {
  vec3 absv = abs(v);
  float z   = max(absv.x, max(absv.y, absv.z));
  return uFarNear.x + uFarNear.y / z;
}

float shadowCoef() {
  vec3  L;
  float d;

  L = vPosWS - light.position_ws;
  d = depthValue(L);

  return texture(uShadMap, vec4(L, d));
}
```

This may require uniform model matrix if you only have ModelViewProjection (MVP)

Here how to calculate uNearFar at client side:

```
  float n, f, nfsub, nf[2];

  n = sm->near;
  f = sm->far;

  nfsub = f - n;
  nf[0] = (f + n) / nfsub * 0.5f + 0.5f;
  nf[1] =-(f * n) / nfsub;

  glUniform2f(gkUniformLoc(prog, "uFarNear"), nf[0], nf[1]);
```

this is just optimization but you don't have to use this and follow the link which I mentioned before.

You may need bias value, related answer uses bias but I'm not sure how to apply it to cubemap correctly. I'm not sure d -+ 0.0001 is correct way or not.

If you want to store world distances in cubemap then this tutorial seems god one: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Point-Shadows

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but that was it! You saved me a ton of debugging, in the C++ code. I should've read up on it before hand. Anyways thanks for the references and everything!